# ListView won't populate (from file)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to populate a **ListView** from a `.txt` file but somehow fail to it.
The file read and is added to the **ArrayList** properly. I have tried the **ArrayAdapter** to the **ArrayList** and set it as the Adapter of the ListView under `OnCreate()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after the list is updated.

I'm fairly new to java, I'm more used to (and prefer) C#

Here's parts of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = null;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = null;
ListView listView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_Run);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.clear();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

//<...>

```
            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")){
                Button btn = new Button(ll1.getContext());
                btn.setText(file.getName().replace(".txt", ""));
                btn.setTag(file.getName().replace(".txt", ""));
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        String btnString = v.getTag().toString();
                        UpdateList(btnString);
                    }
                });
                btn.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ll1.addView(btn);
            }
```

//<...>

```
public void UpdateList(String btnString){
    try{
        File file = new File(runs.getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + btnString + ".txt");
        arrayList = getFileContent(file.getAbsolutePath());
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

//<...>

```
public static ArrayList<String> getFileContent(String fileName) throws IOException{
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    File aFile = new File(fileName);
    BufferedReader reader;  
    String aLine;

    if (!aFile.isFile()){
        return result;
    }
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return result;
    }
    while ((aLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
        result.add(aLine + "\n");
    }
    reader.close();

    return result;
}
```

//<...>

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:background="#ff000000"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:id="@+id/pan_MasterPan">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/pan_Left">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:id="@+id/pan_SelRun">

            <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/select_run"
            android:id="@+id/btn_LoadRun"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="runSelectClick"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:id="@+id/pan_RunPOI">

            <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_Run"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff1A1A1A"
            android:id="@+id/pan_Right">

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ForDebug"
        android:text="@string/debugbtnstrg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="ForDebug_OnClick"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Two days I try this and that without any difference between every try...

Thanks a lot for you time, it's really appreciated.

**---- Edit ----**

Updated Code: (sorry to show only parts, this is part of a massive and messy code...)

```
public void UpdateList(String btnString){
    try{
        File file = new File(runs.getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + btnString + ".txt");
        arrayList = getFileContent(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aL_Size: " + arrayList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
//return 5
        arrayAdapter.addAll(arrayList);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aA_Count: " + arrayAdapter.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
//return 5
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---- Edit 2 ----

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_Run);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.add("TEST1");
        arrayList.add("TEST2");
        arrayList.add("TEST3");
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [ArrayAdapter.addAll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29) method for adding new items in current adapter of ListView before calling `notifyDataSetChanged` :

```
   arrayList = getFileContent(file.getAbsolutePath());
   arrayAdapter.addAll(arrayList);
   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: TheJ0y, you are calling notifyDataSetChanged without adding anything to the adapter.. Prosper K is right here.. Upvoted for him..

Comment: Thanks, it was in fact a missing part. But I still get nothing :( (Seems I can't upvote without a minimum of 15 rep. sorry)

Comment: @TheJ0y: Show updated code and also check how many items you have in `arrayList` before calling `addAll`

Comment: @TheJ0y: what size `"aL_Size: "` Toast message is showing ?

Comment: "aL_Size: 5". I checked the adaptor, also 5(or the good amount of line depending on which file I select(5, 7 or 10)).

Comment: @TheJ0y: ok try to add some items in arrayList after  `arrayList.clear();` line then check ListView is showing or not ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: Still nothing :(

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: Got it! Reloaded the editor, runned from new emulator and its there!  Thanks a lot!